# Getting strange misplaced \noalign error

Tags: errors, rules

I'm trying to add a horizontal line to my document, like so:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage, graphicx, url}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}



$ \mathds{C}$

\hline

\end{document}
```

however, this seems to generate an error message:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.10 \hline
```

The error message is not particularly helpful to me - I can see that `\hline` is mapped to a `\noalign`, but I don't understand why this makes the `\noalign` misplaced.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`\hline` is for use within `tabular`, perhaps you want  `\hrule`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage, graphicx, url}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}

$ \mathds{C}$

\hrule

\end{document}
```